# Why does the sonar plugin in jenkins build everything again?

Tags: hudson, jenkins, sonarqube, hudson-plugins

I installed Jenkins on my build machine and in the Jenkins config checked the box to run sonar analysis on my maven based project. It works but if I look at the log my entire project is built twice. Once from maven and once for sonar (still using maven). Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sonar analysis is performed through a maven plugin. So, whenever you start a sonar analysis, maven will run through all phases that come before the sonar phase, meaning that it will also run the compile and the test phase.

This means, if you want to do a Sonar analysis, you can make a Free-Style Job in Jenkins, configure no Build Step, and only activate the Sonar button. That should work, and should only build your code project once.